# How to reset all settings their original state?

Tags: reset

I know, silly me, I didn't make a backup of the original state the moment I installed US.
Then I naively played with the Main menu using the Menu Editor, and now I can't orbit around objects in Blender using Alt as before. Not to mention that it screwed with the directories I originally had.

Thanks guys,

DPC

Comment: Could you be more specific about the settings of what ?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't change anything with root permissions (like in the /etc or /usr/share directory) you can always delete the folders `~/.APPLICATION_NAME`, `~/.config/APPLICATION_NAME`, `~/.cache/APPLICATION_NAME`, `~/.local/share/APPLICATION_NAME` and the folders will be recreated with default settings after you reboot or relaunch the application (the symbol ~ means your home folder which in my case is /home/thanos). In fact you can delete anything inside your home folder (you might get an error if you delete the trash folder) but you will loose any data that is in there (for example bookmarks in firefox, panel items configuration, installed games in steam, playonlinux's virtual drives or whatever), so keep a copy or choose wisely what you delete.
For example in  order to restore chromium settings you need to delete the folder `~/.config/chromium` and it will be recreated when you relaunch chromium (delete the whole folder in order to be recreated not just some files in it).

If you have changed something with root permissions and you haven't kept a backup, I don't think there's any way to restore settings to their original state without purging and reinstall the applications that you have problem with.

For example to completely reset chromium:

- Run in terminal:`sudo apt-get purge chromium` (you can also use synaptic).
- Delete the folders `~/.cache/chromium` and `~/.config/chromium`
- Run in terminal `sudo apt-get install chromium` (you can also use synaptic or software center).

Comment: Or... total annihilation. Delete and recreate the user account. Just kiddin'

Comment: Ok. I hear you.
What about Resetting the Desktop as advised for Ubuntu 14.04?
1) Reinstall ubuntu desktop

Execute in terminal or tty: sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

**2) Reset compiz **

dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ (Source: ubuntu handbook)

**3) Reset Unity **

http://askubuntu.com/questions/588351/how-do-i-reset-ubuntu

Comment: You can try that, but i don't know what it does exactly as I don't use unity  (ubuntu default desktop) neither compiz, but mate desktop with marco.

Comment: Could you explain about the "Tilde, slash and Dot (~/.)" preceding the file's location?
Are they supposed to be hidden files? I didn't see any of them in the etc nor the usr/share directories.

Comment: the symbol ~ means your home folder (/home/thanos is mine). The dot in the beginning of a name is indeed a hidden file (you can enable seeing hidden files from your file manager preferences, or usually with ctrl+h keyboard combination).