# Resetting Ubuntu

Tags: 16.10, reset

How to factory data reset my Ubuntu ?
I really love Ubuntu(Linux) but i think there should be a software to backup all my system settings just like windows.
 Thank you

Comment: Look at this topic http://askubuntu.com/questions/588351/how-do-i-reset-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not simple to backup system settings* but there's an answer for that [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/7811/125220). To factory data reset you might as well reinstall Ubuntu. Follow the instructions [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) to make a bootable Ubuntu USB stick if you haven't already and then [install Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) from it. You'll want to use the option 'Erase disk and install Ubuntu' when you get to it, presuming you're not dualbooting.

*<sub>I suppose if you want an easy option in Ubuntu to do this you could try reporting a bug on Launchpad with the command `ubuntu-bug` asking for it but you will be submitting a feature request so it will probably be ignored.</sub>

Comment: I know that mate i just don't want to do it.I was looking for an easy way to do it,any way thanks for trying to help....